# Displaying text on TextView by writing on to canvas - Text getting trimmed

Tags: android, textview, android-canvas

In one of my project, I am trying to display text on TextView by writing the text on to canvas using custom draw method. But the top of the text is getting trimmed. I could see some empty space in the bottom half of the text view. Which made be thinking that I am writing the text outside of the canvas. But I set the canvas origin to (0,0) before writing.

```
 @Override
    public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom,
            @NonNull Paint paint)
    {
        if (start >= end) {
            return;
        }

            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(0,0);

            final List<Strings> elements = mUtil.getElements();
            int y1 = 0;

            for(final String element: elements) {
                canvas.drawText(element,
                        start,
                        end,
                        0,
                        y1,
                        paint);
                y1 += mUtil.getLineHeight();
            }
    }



In the above code, I am writing each line at (x,y).
Line 1 (x, y) = (0,0)
Line 2 (x, y) = (0, lineHeight)
Line 3 (x, y) = (0, lineHeight*2)
.....
```

But on the screen all I could see is half of the text getting trimmed off. can someone please correct my understanding of writing the text on to canavs. On my internet search history I figured out that canvas is a 2D plan with (0,0) as origin at top left corner and (n,m) (where n,m are very very large numbers) at the bottom right corner. So I started writing the text at (0,0) But its getting trimmed off :(

Comment: @Suragch any thoughts?

Comment: The `drawText()` method is slightly different than the other draw methods. Instead of the passed coordinates pointing to the top-left corner of the drawn object, for `drawText()`, the coordinates point to the _left baseline_ of the text.

Answer (score 0):

After spening some time with canvas, I figured that there is a gravity field that messing up the rendering.

For a plain TextView, we can start rendering on canvase from (0, ascent). Since the text rendering starts from ascent point.